# How many different ways can you sum $n$ numbers?

Tags: combinatorics

Given an array of different positive integers such as:

$\{1,10,3,5,6,7,8,9,2,4\} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ n\ =\ 10$

How many different combinations of these numbers can you create? Meaning, in how many ways can you sum them?

I'm interested in the worst-case scenario actually trying to match each number with each other. I don't care if there are repetitions, and even if we get twice the same sum, that'll count as two different ways.

Thank you!

Comment: does $1$ number count as a sum i.e. can 1 be a sum

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  If you count, say, $\{1+2\}$ as distinct from, say, $\{3\}$, then why wouldn't the answer be $2^n$, the number of subsets of your set?

Comment: you must clarify the question about what is a "combination" for you

Comment: Are addition as well as subtraction allowed

Comment: Also lulu I agree except $2^n - 1$ as the null set wouldn't apply here

Comment: Why should the empty sum not be considered a sum?  It is as valid of a sum as any singleton sum is...

Comment: Also number themselves count as sums, so $1$ counts. For lulu the results might be $2^{n}$, I don't know, that's what I'm asking. For Ryan only additions no subtractions. The empty sum is not an option in this case.

Comment: That said... in your example array... you have some numbers appearing multiple times (*the number $1$ appeared twice*).  Is this intentional?  Does the "first" $1$ count as "different" than the second one?  In the end, this is rather ambiguous and poorly worded.  It may help if you were to have a small example of maybe two or three numbers, and show us all of the possible things you are wanting to count there.

Comment: I edited the question, changed it to "different positive integers", now the problem should be easier.

Comment: It might help us understand what you are asking for if you gave a smaller exampe where you can explicitly list all the combinations.

Comment: No, the problem is much harder if you want different sums.  If you distinguish $1+2$ and $3$ then the answer is $2^n$ or $2^n-1$ if you want to exclude the empty sum.  If you want to identity things like $1+2$ and $3$ then the answer will depend on the actual numbers in your set.

Comment: I don't think there's a better way to count the possible sums other than to find all of them in this case.

Comment: Lulu, as I said in the post, the sums 2+1 and 3 count as two different options.

Comment: Do $1+2$ and $2+1$ count as different sums?

Comment: This seems relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1919537/how-many-pairwise-distinct-sums-are-there-in-a-finite-set-of-consecutive-integer

Comment: One way to approach this is to solve the subset sum problem for each integer from $1$ to the sum of all elements of the set.